# Underline text within table

Tags: tables

I want to underline a short text and at the same time want the underline to span the width of that column according to the text width.
This is what i tried but i have to manually specify the makebox width:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{Name:}   \noindent\underline{\makebox[2.5in][l] {Joe}}   & \textbf{Roll No:}  \noindent\underline{\makebox[2in][l] {008}} \\
\textbf{School:} \noindent\underline{\makebox[3.15in][l] {SCEE}} & \textbf{Date of Registration:} \noindent\underline{\makebox[1.11in][l] {July 28, 2013}} 
\end{tabular}
```

Can we do this automatically and in minimal coding way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to show that it can be done. It is not a good solution to the problem

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\fillline{\leaders \hbox{\rule[-0.75ex]{0.4pt}{0.4pt}}\hfill\kern0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}<{\fillline}  p{7cm} <{\fillline} }
\textbf{Name:}   \rlap{Joe}
& \textbf{Roll No:} \rlap{008} \\
\textbf{School:} \rlap{SCEE} & \textbf{Date of Registration:} 
\rlap{July 28, 2013} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```